# How to extract lines from a text file, where a string appears several times?

Tags: regex, ultraedit

I have a text file with several lines. In every line there appears a certain string either once or several times. I want to extract all lines where the string appears more than once and write these lines to a separate text file.

My attempt would go over regular expressions and I would do find & replace in UltraEdit. How would the RegEx in UltraEdit look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 regular expression engines available in UltraEdit for Windows since v12.00.

The regular expression is simple on using any of the three expressions.

**UltraEdit** regular expression search string: `string?+string`

`?` does not match newline characters. So a line must contain `string` twice with other characters except newline characters between.

**Unix** or **Perl** regular expression search string: `string.+string`

`.` does not match newline characters (by default). So a line must contain `string` twice with other characters except newline characters between.

With **Perl** it is also possible to use `\bstring\b.+\bstring\b` if a positive match should require that `string` is a complete word excluding for example a line containing `strings or substring`.

The lines producing a positive match can be written to **Find String List** window with find option *List lines containing string* checked and copied from this window via context menu into a new file.

It is also possible to use find option *Filter lines* with *Show* selected to get displayed only lines containing `string` at least two times.

Further a **Find in Files** with option *Open files* selected and option *Results to edit window* checked can be executed to get the found lines into a new file without or with additional information according to configuration as defined at **Advanced - Settings** or **Configuration - Search - Set Find Output Format**. Of course it is also possible to run same **Find in Files** without option *Results to edit window* checked to get the found lines written to active output window tab.

And there are UltraEdit scripts documented at [Find strings with a regular expression and output them to new file](http://forums.ultraedit.com/topic12866.html) to grep from active file strings using a regular expression into a new file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about UltraEdit, but this is easy grep-able. `grep .*STRING.*STRING.* myfile.file > output.file`

This will search `myfile.file` for any line with two occurrences of `STRING` and outputs it to the file `output.file`.

If Windows, use `findstr .*STRING.*STRING.* myfile.file > output.file`. Same result, check `output.file` for the full lines that contain two (or more) occurrences of `STRING`.